# Dynamically adding method/state to a class/instance with name/value determined at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to dynamically add a class method with a name determined at runtime, and also an internal state that is determined at runtime. Here is the simplest example I can cook up:

```
class foo():
    pass

def h(self):   # h() is just a placeholder until we can do setattr()
    state = 'none'
    return state

setattr(h,'state','something')
setattr(foo,'bar',h)
del(h)

print(dir(foo))         # includes 'bar'
print(dir(foo.bar))     # includes 'state'
print(getattr(foo.bar,'state')) # 'something'

f = foo()
print(getattr(f.bar,'state'))    # 'something'

# all is well up to here, but now we go awry
print(f.bar())   # 'none'
```

In the last line, the bar() return statement seems to be bound to the original definition in h() rather than its new context in foo. I have tried numerous things, and looked at introspection and other topics in stack overflow, but come up empty. How can I modify this code so that the last line yields 'something'?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the *local variable* `state` inside `h`, which has nothing to do with the attribute on the function object, `h.state`. They are not related... Note, `f.bar.state` will give you `'something'`.

You could could do something like this:

```
In [6]: class Foo: pass

In [7]: def h(self):
   ...:     return self.state
   ...:

In [8]: Foo.bar = h

In [9]: f = Foo()

In [10]: f.state = 'something'

In [11]: f.bar()
Out[11]: 'something'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you are heading me in the right direction! I am reading more about attributes, and how they relate to variables.  What I would like to do is set both the method name and the state it returns dynamically at run time, and make this change to the class rather than the instance as you have done. I will work on this and get back with any code that works or more questions if I fail.